# Xamarin.Android with MvvmCross has frequest MvxLayoutInflater.java java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Crashes

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am working with Xamarin.Android with MvvmCross 5.1.1 .
My App mostly consumes REST Api and uses ListViews & RecylerViews. I am getting frequest crash reports from stores and the frequest crashes Says 
`MvxLayoutInflater.java with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

 
I have also set the `Java Max Heap size` to `1G` .

but the same is also not fixing this issue. Is there a better way to handle or fix this?

Comment: `Java Max Heap size to 1G` is a build time Java option in `Xamarin.Android` MSBuild calls and has nothing to do with the Android app runtime. You need to profile your app and determine were the memory is being allocated and what you are not releasing. *Typically* the largest memory consumers are Bitmaps that are not properly `.Release`'d but memory profiling will determine that.

Comment: Please post the whole exception stack trace.

Comment: Are you using images in your app? I've had similar crashes where my layouts were using too big images on smaller devices.